# Setting minimum height for the output cell in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way how I could set the minimum height for the output cell in Jupyter?

### Issue

I am experiencing flicking display issues when clearing my output with `clear_output(wait=True)`. When clear_output() executes, it clears the output cell so that the cell collapses down to a single line (1 row). If you output multiple lines too fast, it results in a flicker: the output cell collapses down to 1 line after clearing and then expands to multiple line as you do multiple `print()` calls in a row.

### Solution I tried

I expect that if I set the minimum height for the output cell, this will eliminate the flicker as it will effectively prevent the output cell to collapse down to single line upon calling `clear_output(wait=True)`.

I thought this might help, but it didn't.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { min-height:100em !important; }</style>"))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand what you are trying to achieve but `container` is most probably not the class that you want to modify.

Each cell consists of input and output where output is rendered only when there is something to render and this is decided on the fly when you run the code in the input section.

So, do you want to set maximum height to only those outputs that have something in them or to all outputs even if there is nothing to be shown?

In case you care only about the outputs where there is something to be shown then you set `min-height` on `.output_area` class.

```py
CSS = ".output_area { min-height: 10em; }"
HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

If you want to force all outputs to have `min-height`, even those that would otherwise be hidden, you can set it on `.output_wrapper` instead.

```py
CSS = ".output_wrapper { min-height: 10em; }"
HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

Comment: matus-dubrava, thank you for your help. Sadly, this didn' thelp. When `clear_output(wait=True)` invokes, it still not only clears the output area but it also makes the output area to *collapse* down to a single line. This behavior generates an annoying flicking effect: output area clears and collapses. If I print several lines afterwads, the output area expands to fit these lines. And so it does on every run where I need to print lines. So I thought I could avoid this flicker if I could allocate enough room in output area to always fit all the lines that I print out.